# Why am I getting an error saying 'Missing parameter' in this redash query?

Tags: mysql, redash

I am running this query in Redash but getting a 'Missing parameter value' error. Any fix/reason for this?

[image]

The i.due_date has date, time and seconds.

Thanks!

Comment: you have not provided start and end date values

Comment: Hi Amit! I did provide start and end dates (see i.due_date box at the bootom ofv the picture attached)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you modify your jinja syntax. While you are comparing a value with the table alias i, it does not mean anything in jinja.

Instead of { i.due_date.start } and { i.due_date.end },
try { due_date.start }  and { due_date.end }